# Copy all files from a directory tree into one directory

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, cygwin, file-transfer

I'm running on Windows but have Cygwin so Windows or simple Linux versions are both OK.

My camera-phone stores images in a directory tree based on date, but still appears to name each file uniquely. I want to copy all files into one directory on my PC without all the sub-dirs. How can I do this?

Copying with sub-dir structure is easy: `xcopy f:\images\*.jpg C:\Users\Me\Pictures\Phone`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in PowerShell:

```
dir f:\images -recurse -filt *.jpg | copy -dest C:\Users\Me\Pictures\Phone
```

Note:
- This will overwrite files with the same name already in the destination even if resulting from this copy
- Add a `-verbose` to the `copy` to see what is being copied.

Answer (score 6):

Try this in cygwin:

```
find /cygdrive/f/images -name '*.jpg' -exec cp '{}' /cygdrive/c/Users/Me/Pictures/Phone \;
```

Comment: try `-iname` for case-insensitive matches, some cameras use Uppercase.

Comment: And try replacing the `\;` with `+` for marginally faster results (this will execute one `cp` for all the files, rather than one per file).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all this was useful thread and Power shell line works perfect

**dir f:\images -recurse -filt *.jpg | copy -dest C:\Users\Me\Pictures\Phone**

if you have **15 GB** of pictures some lost ones don't relay matter anymore.. :D 
**Thanks Richard :)**

Comment: You don't have to repeat someones answer please write a comment instead

Comment: @yass is right, that would fit better as a comment. Since you don't have enough reputation to comment, I suggest you read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/349538)